# Why is this short SQL file giving me errors?

Tags: mysql, sql

Here's the file:

```
ALTER TABLE tablename
    ADD COLUMN `column_name` varchar(255) NULL;
```

I'm getting this error on line one:

`ERROR 1064 (42000): YOu have an error in your SQL syntax; ... line 1`

Why is this?

I'm certain the table name and column name are typed properly as there are other similar sql files that I am basing this one off of.

Comment: Nothing wrong with this syntax or the code you posted as I just tested it. What is the **exact** code you are using?

Comment: That is the exact code I just replaced the table and column names. I'm certain they're valid since they're identical in other files. I'm calling the file like such: `mysql < data/MyFile.sql;`

Comment: What is the exact error message? Copy paste it as-is, without any `...` substitutions

Comment: `ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'data/MyFile.sql' at line 1.`

Comment: As you can see in the error message - it doesn't run the file, but it tries to run the file name as a command. What and how do you call?

Comment: You need to provide the **EXACT** code. No substitution.

Comment: @zerkms: I try to call the file from within the mysql command prompt like such: `mysql < data/MyFile.sql;` and get that error message.

Comment: Perhaps you've got a character encoding issue in your file. Maybe try manually reentering the sql into a clean file.

Comment: Are you using command line or shell?

Comment: @njk: Not sure what the difference is. I'm using putty to ssh in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're entering `mysql < MyFile.sql` within the MySQL command prompt.

You need to run it from your *shell*.  It's a different way of running `mysql` itself, not a special `mysql` command.

Answer (score 2):

If you call it from mysql command prompt, you need to use this:

```
source path/to/file.sql;
```

or call what you're calling now from the shell.